# PDF generation with Dompdf not working for large data

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am using Dom pdf to generate a pdf file. IF there are 1000 records in table format of html then it takes minimum 20 minutes to generate but most of the time it displaying the following
error

- No data received error 324
- data segmentation error.
- Error 500 server down

Is there any other easy way to generate ? or any solutions ?

My Controller code:

$view = new View($this, false);
    $html = $view->element('reports_affiliate');

```
    ini_set("max_execution_time","-1");
    $q = new DOMPDF($html);
    $q->load_html($html);
    $q->render();
    $pdf = $q->output();
    $q->stream( gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT".".pdf");
```

Please note that there is no problem in my sql queries or template files.

Comment: based on that information, no solutions

Comment: With such little information this is just a guessing game. You'll at least have to provide some sample code reproducing the problem.

Comment: question updated .. now shoot ur solutions or comments :)

Comment: If the problem is in dompdf and not other portions of your code it would help to see a sample of the HTML output instead of the generation code.

Comment: I removed the DOM PDF.. the issue is already existing one of DOMPDF. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/550 .. and now i am using TCPDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've a lot of problem with the same library.
To avoid them, I've changed the script, adopting [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) library . It's very simply to install and use, also good performance.
If you need high performance, use Zend_PDF module.